# How to close web browser in c language?

Tags: c, browser, process, terminate

Lets say Google chrome or the broader question would be how to kill any process in Windows OS.
For example I have opened link and default web browser and want to close it.

```
void main(){
ShellExecute(NULL, "open", "www.google.com", NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A rather simple, unportable way:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

system("taskkill /IM chrome.exe /F");
```

- For details on the `system()` call, see: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/system-call-in-c/
- For details on `taskkill`, see: https://ss64.com/nt/taskkill.html